# Options page textarea to populate custom post select field

Tags: plugins, pages, options

I have created a plugin that allows entry of a custom post type. Within that post type I have a select metabox for name. I also have an options page that has a textarea box that has a list of names. I have been unsuccessful at connecting the 2 together. The idea is to have the list from the textarea show as the options for the select box in the plugin. any direction on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Code in options page for Textarea

```
<th scope="row">Name</th>
    <td><textarea id="name" name="name" rows="5" cols="36"><?php echo esc_attr( get_option('name') ); ?></textarea></td>
```

Code in Plugin for select box

```
$options = get_option( 'name' );

$names = explode( "", $options['name'] );
?>

<select name="Name">
<?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
printf(
    '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
    $name,
    $name
);
} ?>
```

[image: Image of the admin area not the var_dump shows Michelle but the name in the select box is John.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_option` to get your option values. Below is an example

```
<?php
$selected_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_meta_key', true );
$options = get_option( 'your_options' );
// If your names are separeated with comma
$names = explode( PHP_EOL, $options);
?>

<select name="your-select-name">
<?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
    printf(
        '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
        $name,
        selected( $name, $selected_name, false ),
        $name
    );
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @JohnLucey What you get if you `var_dump( get_option( 'name' )`?

Comment: How do I post Code into this forum? I would love to show it here so you could look at it but I have had no success with that either. Ever feel like the world is working against ya lol?

Comment: You can try [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Oh no I meant how do I past the code in here like you did above with the grey box and formatting and all.

Comment: Oh, click curly braces from the editor. Code must be indented four spaces.

Comment: Multi line code works only in answers not in comments. Edit your original question.

Comment: edited the first post

Comment: What you get if you add `var_dump( get_option( 'name' );` before `$names = exp...`?

Comment: It breaks the plugin and gives a blank screen

Comment: Try setting `WP_DEBUG` to true https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Ok so it gave an illegal string offset for your original code. I removed the 'name' portion that came after $options in explode command and it shows the list. so only problem left is I did not use commas to separate it was each item on a new line. so how do I separate via line break in explode command?

Comment: I updated my answer's `explode()`

Comment: That did it, it is functioning just as I expected it to. What do I do to give you the Kudos for helping me through this, first time in the forums.

Comment: Great, click up arrow on my answer

Comment: I click the up arrow and it did not change, I clicked the check mark and it turned green but the up arrow does nothing at all. I really appreciate your help. I hope one day I can do the same for someone else now that I am in the forum. I think its because I am new that it does not change the point.

Comment: how would you show current database option as selected.

Comment: @JohnLucey updated my answer, check [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and [selected](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected)

Comment: @ville6000-I have added an image, I had tried something similar and had the exact same result. It still defaults back to the first option in the list. See image above. I even went as far as to strip every ounce of code from the file that did not need to be there to see if the issue was a conflict but still fails.